# Optimize a CSS3 animation that uses CSS masks

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm working on a CSS3-based animation, where I have a div that has a linear-gradient as the background, and then I use a PNG as the mask using the -webkit-mask-image property.

To make it animated, I want to move the mask on top of the gradient. It's working fine and looks gorgeous, but my issue is it kinda kills the CPU.

Here's the animation:

```
@keyframes moveMask {
    0%  { -webkit-mask-position: 0px 0px;}
    100% { -webkit-mask-position: 2000px 0px; }
}
```

And I'm calling it using this:

```
animation: moveMask 200s linear infinite alternate;
```

I've tried to add the following trick, but it didn't change anything:

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Any idea on how I can optimize it?

Comment: You'll probably find that the webkit mask isn't optimised in webkit at all – it's not used very much and hence probably hasn't had many people looking at it.

Comment: yea it's a non-standard method, I don't think there is much you can do to optimize it other than not use it and find a new solution by some other means. Some of the heavy animation non-standard methods are really experimental at this point still and even though they exist; probably shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

As Rich Bradshaw pointed out, I think you will find that it's just not very well optimized. To achieve a similar sort of effect though, you could create an animated GIF, double the canvas size, and then place a static version of the GIF on every frame of the other half of the canvas. That way, the animation would always be playing invisibly in the background and you'd just switch to it by changing the position of the image whenever you wanted to show the animated version.

A problem with this technique is that the animation won't necessarily start at the beginning when you trigger it. That may or may not be important for your particular animation.